# How do I stream audio to my HomePod minis without using Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, airplay, streaming, homepod

I have a pair of HomePod minis connected to an Apple TV 4K, which is connected to a projector.

Is there a way to stream directly to the HomePod minis from my iPhone without “waking up” the Apple TV and projector?

I swear there used to be, but now I only see the HomePod minis and appletv listed as a single block in AirPlay sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Good question!  I wasn't sure myself, so I just tried.  I started playing locally on my iPhone, in Spotify.  I used the OS's AirPlay controls to select my "ATV+HomePodMinis", and the music came out of the Minis.

The light on the ATV never turned on, but that wasn't good enough.  I unplugged the power cord from the ATV and the music kept playing on the Minis.

If your setup needs your ATV to be powered on, you might have a different config in the Home app for your combo, or maybe different settings in the ATV itself (but I'd look in the Home app first).